# Check if image is black

Tags: android, python, image-processing, monkeyrunner

I'm running a Python script under Windows which deals with 480x800 `PNG` images with 32-bit depth. I need to check if the given image is fully black or not. After some searching I've found that ImageMagick could help me to achieve this but unfortunately there's no manual for such task.

So a more general question is how to check if the image consists only of one color?

**Edit:**

My apologies for not providing all the information about the environment from beginning. The python script is executed using Android's [`monkeyrunner`](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html). Since it uses it's own instance of Jython (version 2.5) it's not possible to use any modules from external libraries. Inside there's a `MonkeyImage` class to work with screenshots taken from the device. So I adopted @eumiro's answer for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import Image
im = Image.load("image.png")
diff_colors = list(set(im.getdata()))
if len(diff_colors) == 1 and diff_colors[0] == (0, 0, 0):
    print "all black"
```

**EDIT** as @JonClements proposes, this will be faster and stop as soon as anything else than black is found:

```
import Image
im = Image.load("image.png")
if all(rgb == (0,0,0) for rgb in im.getdata()):
    print "all black"
```

Comment: `if all(rgb == (0,0,0) for rgb in im.getdata())` ?

Comment: Didn't have `Image` module in my environment used this as a sample to solve the problem, thanks

Comment: @AndreyErmakov It's a useful library (`PIL`) - certainly wouldn't hurt to have it installed ;)

Comment: @JonClements I'm actually running it inside Android's `monkeyrunner` which seems to use it's own Jython instance inside. So I used the same approach with a `MonkeyImage` object it provides.

Comment: @AndreyErmakov Great! Perhaps you'd be so kind as to update your question with that information, so others in the future find it more easily?

Answer (score 1):

I am no expert in Python but I saw that there is a PNG module that you can use.
Load the PNG and export it to an RGB(A) array.

Checking if it is totally black should then be simple. Run through the array and make sure nothing differs from 0.

I think this should work.

Out of curiosity, why would you want to check if the image is black?